# Gremlin - Expecting valueMap values are as a string instead of array

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

1. `g.V(VertexId).valueMap("tags")` returns

```json
{'tags': ['My Last Day', 'Poor Connection > Netenter code herework Issue', 'Or Hello > Equals Hi > Last Message ', 'Network Issue', 'Last Message ']}
```

2. `g.V(VertexId).valueMap("tags").by(unfold())` returns

```json
{'tags': 'My Last Day'}
```

Expecting like this:

```json
{'tags': "My Last Day, Poor Connection > Netenter code herework Issue, Or Hello > Equals Hi > Last Message, Network Issue, Last Message"}
```

Comment: Finally found solution, Please refer this link https://catwolf.org/qs?id=f7c1b2b2-2ce6-4192-9aff-ca8edeaa482e&x=y

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to return a set of multi-properties for "tags" as a single string. So the question really is how to concatenate each multi-property together to a single string in Gremlin.

The answer at this time is that you can't. There are no string concatenation options in Gremlin at this time, unless you can use a lambda (which won't work for Neptune and are generally [discouraged for a number of reasons](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-lambdas) anyway). You will need to return all the multi-properties and then concatenate them in your application. It is possible that that we will see string concatenation functions for [TinkerPop 3.7.0](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/future/#roadmap).

Comment: Hi @stephen, Thanks for your response. Finally found solution, Please refer this link https://catwolf.org/qs?id=f7c1b2b2-2ce6-4192-9aff-ca8edeaa482e&x=y


g.V().valueMap().by(choose(
      count(local).is(eq(1)),
      unfold()
 ))

Comment: oh, i see what you wanted now.